# How to limit product list?

Tags: magento-1.8, catalog

How can show the newest product up to 3 items only?

This is my new.phtml,

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>

<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="row items-highlight">
        <?php endif ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?> col-lg-4" style="border:1px solid black;">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image') ?>" width="355" height="auto" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?>" class="img-responsive"/></a>
             </li>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==count($_products)): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It shows as many items as in my product collection. Can I get 3 items only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newest product related block is "Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New", "DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT" this variable is control, how many you need to show. So change this value as required.

Don't forget to overwrite this block.